# Can I add personal info to my iPod touch's lock screen?

Tags: ipod-touch, screen-lock

My dad just got a new iPod Touch, and he'd like to add his personal info to the lock screen. If possible, how do I do this (without jailbreaking)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this simply by opening up the **Notes** app, **Adobe Ideas** app, or anything of the like. Add your father's information in either of those applications to your liking. Take a screenshot of the final image by pressing the **Home** button and the **Sleep/Wake** button at the same time, or save the image to your Photos if that option is available within the app of choice itself. Go to **Settings** -> **Wallpaper** -> select the image you just captured/created, and then save it to your **Lock Screen**. Rejoice!

Comment: I ended up using this method rather than the others because it was the simplest and cheapest way. Thanks so much for your helpful answer!

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way to go about this without jailbreaking is to use some custom wallpaper.

Make a new document in Photoshop, Pixelmator, GIMP, or your editor of choice.

Find a high-resolution image on the Web that you like and copy it into the document. Crop it to 640 x 960 pixels.

Add some text with your personal info over the image. Make sure that you leave ~225px space at the top of the image and ~150 at the bottom (these will be covered by the unlock UI). A subtle drop shadow can help make the text easier to read.
Export the image is a JPEG or PNG.

[image]

Use your preferred method to get the photo onto your iPod (sync with iTunes, email to yourself, Dropbox app, etc.).

On the iPod, go to Settings-> Wallpaper and select your custom image. You can set it as wallpaper for only the lock screen or the lock screen and home screen.

You'll now have custom text on the lock screen:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I did some research and came up with several paid apps.

> All of these apps does not automatically update the lock screen (weather, calendar, etc portions). Some of them will send you a scheduled reminder to update the image, then opening the app, you'll be able to update the image.
> Reading some reviews, many users bought these apps thinking they would get something that you simply can't do with non jailbroken devices: automatic lock screen updates.

### [Lock Screen](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lock-screen/id402793319?mt=8)

It adds not only personal info, but weather and calendar notifications to the lock screen:

[image: Lock screen screenshot]
[image: Lock screen screenshot #2]

### [Screen Maker](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/screen-maker-home-screen-lock/id475276154?mt=8)

Adds a lot more than just the lock screen. It also allows you to make changes to the home screen as well:

[image: Screen maker]

### [If Found Lock Screen](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/if-found-lock-screen/id398340788?mt=8)

Simple and easy...adds personal info to the lock screen. I think this may be what we'll go with.

[image: If found lock screen screenshot]

### [Smart Lockscreen creator](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/smart-lockscreen-creator/id419890996?mt=8)

Adds a little more functionality than the rest...calendar, weather, quotes, etc.

[image: Smart Lockscreen Creator screenshot]